# Embed python in a website

Tags: python, html, web, embed

I'm planning on building a website in which I execute python code stored on my computer. How can I embed python code in a website to make this possible? Is there some syntax in HTML to do this?

Comment: Have you done some Googling?

Comment: Generally, you cannot execute any code other than JS on the client-side.  You could maybe make an AJAX call, have the python run server-side, and send back a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to use conventional CPython code on the client side. However, you can use [Pyjs](http://pyjs.org/) which will translate your Python code to Javascript code or [Brython](http://www.brython.info/) which is an interpreter written in Javascript. Of course, they might have some limitations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user3925758 Depending on what you're trying to do, maybe you can move your Python logic to server-side and just send output to the client.